# Book recommendations on the analysis of randomized algorithms

Tags: algorithm-analysis, randomized-algorithms, books

I would like to read some books (or any other material) that cover the design of randomized algorithms with a particular focus on the analysis. My main goal is to develop the rigour needed to construct the **proof of correctness** for such algorithms.

I am currently reading [Probability and Computing - M. Mitzenmacher, E. Upfal](https://www.cambridge.org/sg/academic/subjects/computer-science/algorithmics-complexity-computer-algebra-and-computational-g/probability-and-computing-randomization-and-probabilistic-techniques-algorithms-and-data-analysis-2nd-edition?format=HB&isbn=9781107154889), which I find to be a good introduction to this topic.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: If you truly want to develop 100% mathematical rigour, you will have to first learn to use a deductive system for FOL (first-order logic), and then you can easily do all mathematics in any field (not just in algorithm analysis) completely rigorously even if you are reading a mathematically sloppy book. I assure you that this is more important than many people think, because I have seen many people who are well-published in top CS journals on algorithms who make basic quantifier errors. You might escape most errors if your intuition is sharp enough, but true rigour requires a full grasp of FOL.

Answer (score 4):

*Randomized Algorithms* by Motwani, Rajeev, and Raghavan contains a lot of excellent material on the design and analysis of algorithms.  They show many proofs of correctness for different randomized algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know if it meets your needs but MIT's OCW site has free lecture notes from a class on the subject here:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-856j-randomized-algorithms-fall-2002/lecture-notes/

It also has assignments and answers here:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-856j-randomized-algorithms-fall-2002/assignments/

The syllabus refers to the book one of the other answers lists and it has links to related OCW classes:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-856j-randomized-algorithms-fall-2002/syllabus/

Maybe this material will help. Nice that they provide free lecture notes as PDF files.

Bobby

Answer (score 1):

The Book 'The Design of approximation algorithms' contains some chapters regarding randomized (approximation) algorithms.

I think it is well written and some algorithms would be easy to understand for 'beginners'.

It is free for everyone https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/index.php